# Retornar 0 caso o valor não exista na tabela

Tags: banco-de-dados, oracle, select

Estou usando o select para verificar se existe SEQ_RESUMO na tabela. Se existir esta me retornando o valor da SEQ_RESUMO, ate ai ok. Porém quando o valor não existe na tabela, segundo o select que fiz, era para retornar 0, mas esta retornando NULL.

```
SELECT 
CASE
    WHEN COUNT(1) = 0 THEN 0
    WHEN COUNT(1) > 0 THEN SEQ_RESUMO
END AS sequence
FROM INICIO_FIM_COLETA WHERE seq_picking = '244582'
GROUP BY SEQ_RESUMO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que seria algo assim, porem nao tenho como testar no momento.

```
SELECT COALESCE( (SELECT SEQ_RESUMO FROM INICIO_FIM_COLETA WHERE seq_picking = '244582'), 0) as sequence 
from INICIO_FIM_COLETA  
group by SEQ_RESUMO
```

Comment: Obrigado @Raquel Andrade, funcionou.

Answer (score 1):

Utilize a função `COALESCE`. Lembre-se de que `NULL` não é a mesma coisa que zero.

```
SELECT SEQ_RESUMO, COALESCE(COUNT(1), 0) AS sequence
FROM INICIO_FIM_COLETA WHERE seq_picking = '244582'
GROUP BY SEQ_RESUMO;
```

Mas no caso de não existir oregsitro buscado o é retorno é zero registros, o que é diferente de retornar um registro com um campo NULL. Tente:

```
SELECT SEQ_RESUMO, COALESCE(COUNT(1), 0) AS sequence
FROM INICIO_FIM_COLETA WHERE seq_picking = '244582'
GROUP BY SEQ_RESUMO
UNION
SELECT '???' AS seq_resumo, 0 AS sequence 
FROM NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INICIO_FIM_COLETA WHERE seq_picking = '244582');
```

Comment: o resultado ainda continua nulo. Essa sequencia que estou usando como exemplo, ela não existe na tabela, então quando alguma sequencia não existir quero retornar 0. Se eu colocar uma sequencia que existe, a sequencia é retornado normalmente como esperado.

Answer (score 0):

faz uma alteração na tabela que voce quer, em especifico na coluna inteira.. assim onde for null substitui para um valor padrão como "0"...

exemplo:

```
ALTER TABLE estoque 
CHANGE COLUMN qtd DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT 0 ;
```